# How do I execute a Azure Data Factory pipeline X times (for X distinct parameter values)?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that is triggered daily at a certain time, which works fine. This pipeline gets the current date as the input parameter, which is also fine.

Now I'm doing an alternative version of that same pipeline **to simulate past dates**, in which the parameter is the date value (for instance '2018-05-23' for May 23rd 2018). However, if I want to run the pipeline for the whole year 2018 (so I'd need 365 distinct parameters), how would I do that?

Of course I could trigger it manually with January 1st, then January 2nd and so on, but that would take forever. I'd like to trigger January 1st and then **sequentially have the pipeline executed** for the other 364 days of the year, once January 1st is finished.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe use a ForEach activity with an array of dates? Should be straightforward to generate a date array to pass as a parameter. And you can set `isSequential` to `true` to make sure the pipelines are generated sequentially (per your specified requirement).

Comment: Thank you @DavidMakogon, I reviewed the option and it should work!

Comment: I went ahead and formalized my comment as an answer. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

So... to loop through a series of dates, I'd suggest populating an input parameter with an array of date values (you can generate this in a straightforward way through code, and pass this as a parameter to your pipeline).

Then, in your pipeline, you can define a ForEach loop, iterating through each of the date entries in your parameter, executing the pipeline for each date.

Based on your requirement to run the pipelines in sequence, without parallelism, just be sure to set `isSequential` to `true` in your pipeline's `ForEach` definition. Something like this, as a simple example:

```
{  
   "name":"...",
   "type":"ForEach",
   "typeProperties":{  
      "isSequential":"true",
        "items": {
            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.datesToProcess",
            "type": "Expression"
        },
      "activities":[  
         { 
            ...
         }
      ]
    }
}
```

You can read more about `ForEach` in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity).